# Removing numeric values from alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all numeric values from a string
But only if the string contains at least one letter.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

For e.g.

```
var s = "asd23asd"
```

Then result must be asdasd

However if

```
var s = "123123"
```

Then result must be 123123 as the string does not have any letters.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I tried using a condition. I just wanted to know if there was a direct way of doing it

Comment: @Roberto i mean the string should contain atleast one character which is some alphabet from a-z

Comment: So `-1` should remain `-1`, or `+2` remain `+2`. What about `a+2` should it be `a` or `a+` and what about whitespace or characters from other alphabets like `å`, `ä` or `ö`, or characters `_!:;,` and so on?

Comment: @Xotic750 my string does not have any special characters other than '-' or '_'. I had already taken care of that case

Comment: So you will have a `-` in you string, what does that represent if all numbers: `-123`, is this a number, `1-23` but this is not?

Comment: There are no special characters in the string on which i will be doing the processing

Comment: So your previous statement was incorrect? `my string does not have any special characters other than '-' or '_'.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function filter(string){
     var result = string.replace(/\d/g,'')
     return result || string;
}
```

or directly

```
var newString = string.replace(/\d/g,'') || string;
```

**Why || works**

the || and & are conditionals operators and sure that you used in if, while ...

If you do somethin like

```
var c1 = false, c2 = true, c3= false, c4 = true;
if( c1 || c2 || c3 || c4) {
}
```

This evaluation will stop in the first moment that is valid or invalid.

this mind that the evaluation stop in c2 this mind that is more fast 
(true || false) than (false || true)

At this point we can add another concept, the operator return always the last element in the evaluation

(false || 'hey' || true) return 'hey', remember in JS 'hey' is true but '' is false

Interesting examples:

```
var example = {
  'value' : {
     'sub_value' : 4
  }
}

var test = example && example.value && example.value.sub_value;
console.log(test) //4

var test_2 = example && example.no_exist && example.no_exist.sub_value;
console.log(test_2) //undefined


var test_3 = example.valno_existue.sub_value; //exception

function test_function(value){
   value = value || 4; //you can expecify default values
}
```

Comment: is g and gi is same?what is the use of gi? @Raúl Martín

Comment: @Raúl Martín fine thanks, before using || string, we are getting the result na,then may i know how it works further?

Comment: I updated, maybe you can edit the question and help me with my English ;)

Comment: @Raúl Martín extremely sorry :(  i could n't understand ji.... and i think no one help for his second requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79764/discussion-between-paps-k-and-raul-martin).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this. First check if the word contains any alphabet, if yes then replace.

```
var s = "asd23asd";
if(/\w+/.test(s))
    s = s.replace(/\d+/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\d+|\d+(?=[a-zA-Z]+)
```

You can try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/27

Answer (score -1):

Javascript Code

```
  var txt='asd23ASd3';
  if(parseInt(txt))
      var parsed=txt;
  else
      var parsed=txt.replace ( /[^a-zA-Z]/g, '');
  console.log(parsed)
```